How to summarize a summarization
I have data where I get an activitystatus and I am doing the following:
| summarize
    Count = dcount(tostring(data.traceId)) by activityStatus = toint(data.activityStatus), result = toint(data.result), resultDetail = tostring(data.resultDetail)

and I get a nice output like this:

What I'd like to do is change this so that I bucket the counts by day, something like this (which obviously doesn't work or I wouldn't be posting here) :)
Count = dcount(tostring(data.traceId)) by activityStatus = toint(data.activityStatus) by bin(timestamp, 1d)

Is this possible?

ok, the SQL guy trying to make it harder that it is, this is all I needed:
| summarize     dcount(tostring(data.traceId)) by bin(timestamp, 1d), activityStatus = toint(data.activityStatus), tostring(data.result)

You can include bin(TimeGenerated, 1d)  along with the other columns in the grouping columns. This would help you in achieving the summarized value for the one day bucket along with other conditions. Below is the correct code,
your_table_name
| summarize Count = dcount(tostring(traceId)) by timestamp = bin(TimeGenerated, 1d), activityStatus = toint(activityStatus), result= toint(result),resultDetail

In this query, bin(TimeGenerated, 1d) buckets the counts by day, and summarize groups the counts by the columns activityStatus, result, resultdetails along with 1day bin timestamp column.
demo
